# Can flow of force be disturbed with technology?

Tags: star-wars, video-games, the-force

I haven't seen it in movies & TV shows (And, no luck regarding novels as I haven't read any). But, in many Star Wars video games, I experience disturbance while using force in some tech environment. Is there any canonical explanation of it? I don't consider video games under canon..

Comment: I'm not sure about technology blocking the force, but in the games I am pretty sure it was a creature that was blocking/absorbing the Force. The name of it eludes me, however.

Comment: It was called a [Ysalamiri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ysalamiri#Ysalamiri).

Comment: @Xantec A living organism seems reasonable, but what about technology?

Answer (score 7):

### Legends Continuity

- [Universal Energy Cage](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Universal_Energy_Cage)

  (first appeared in Dark Empire comics) - Universal Energy Cages were large and were designed with superconductor energy feedback systems that could contain the Force powers of a Jedi and reflect them back twofold.
- The other way around: there was at least one example of a person being able to affect technology through the Force: [Irek Ismaren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Irek_Ismaren). However he did so via a special implant given to him at the age of five.

Comment: Good to know about "Universal Energy Cage", but unable to understand why you put second point... Reverse is not always true!

Comment: @SachinShekhar - to show off :)

Answer (score 4):

### Not that we know of

First, there aren’t any canon examples of technology *in general* disrupting the Force through its mere presence, as the question seems to be suggesting. Indeed, during the years before the Clone Wars, the Jedi Temple was on Coruscant, an entirely urbanized planet that was virtually packed with technology. Technology may be unable to *interact* with the Force, as is apparently<sup>1</sup> the case with droids  (who, lacking midi-chlorians, cannot access the Force) but it does not disrupt it.

Speaking more narrowly, though, there aren’t any specific devices in current canon that can
affect the Force. Previous works mentioned devices such as the [Universal Energy Cage](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Universal_Energy_Cage), but these are now Legends, and thus non-canonical.

On the contrary, it’s perfectly possible for a sufficiently powerful individual to use the Force to affect people through some of the better defenses in *Star Wars*. Witness Darth Sidious using the Force to choke Count Dooku through both Coruscant and Serenno’s planetary shields:

[image]

Visual contact (or at least precise knowledge of their location) seems to still be necessary (as well as considerable skill with the Force), but there’s no denying that the Force can bypass shields.

---

If we expand our definitions a bit, it might be possible to manufacture something that disrupts the Force. For example, the Imperial Inquisitors [used Luminara Unduli’s bones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/148666/51379) to fool surviving Jedi into being captured, suggesting that some element of her Force presence lingered in her remains. It *might* be possible to use the remains of a powerful dark side user, then, to create an object that could disrupt the light side, and give any Jedi in the neighborhood a big headache—but this is very speculative. In any case, this would only pose an obstacle to light side users, and would be quite the opposite for those strong with then dark side.

Similarly, technology created with kyber crystals, which are in tune with the Force, would create a noticeable disturbance in the Force, but wouldn’t disrupt the ability of people to use it, per se.

<sub>1: Consider the frequency of the Force among organics, and the number of sentient droids.</sub>