# Are there any technological defences against the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In part one of the Battle of Geonosis in season 3 of Star Wars Rebels, Ezra and Kanan are confronted by a destroyer droid with a shield in a narrow corridor. They draw their lightsabers to defend themselves, but it seems like it would have made sense to force push the droid back up the passageway to attempt to create space and distract the rest of the droids behind. They certainly have no problems force pushing normal battle droids. I recall similar scenarios in the clone wars but haven't watched that in a while so I can't provide specific examples.

This got me wondering, is there any canon evidence of technology (such as the destoryer's shields) protecting against force powers (such as force push) that goes above and beyond 'normal' limitations of the force (e.g distance, size)?

Comment: Is "being massive" a technological defense? What about "far away" or "small and hard to manipulate"?

Comment: @Adamant I'd argue that they are more just normal limitations of force use

Comment: Example: Grievous has no special defense from Force pushes (besides digging his claws in), but is sturdy enough that using them might merely tire his opponent out.

Comment: I guess having gripping claws/anchors etc to prevent being moved probably counts.

Comment: Canon, **no**. Legends, [**Ysalamiri**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ysalamir).

Comment: Some kind of antibiotics killing midichlorians. Non-canon, of course.

Comment: @Valorum I think the Ysalamiri would be a biological defense. But a [Universal Energy Cage](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Universal_Energy_Cage) would most definitely be a technological defense that exists in Legends.

Comment: @void_ptr Midi-chlorians are necessary for life itself (as Qui-Gon told us), so killing mid-chlorians would kill the force user you're trying to stop (not to mention also hurt non-force users). If you're okay with killing your target, you're probably better off finding another way to kill them than trying to administer an antibiotic during combat.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can flow of force be disturbed with technology](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10077/13217), but that was asked before the Legends/Disney split. Should we close this as a duplicate and add a Disney canon answer to that question, or retag the other one as Legends and keep this one open?

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10490/13217) about this being an exact duplicate of a pre-Disney canon question not marked as being Legends.

Comment: Added a bounty to the other question if any of you are interested.

Comment: Hokey religions and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid.